# AJAX: Data from response not populating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Please help, I fetch the data using ajax and this works fine

```
function fetch_data(){
$.ajax({
    url: '../ajax/ajax_org_select.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: $('#frm_org_id').serialize(),
    success:function(data){
        $('#live_data').html(data);
    }
});
}
fetch_data();
```

However, when i trying to insert data using my other ajax and trying to populate, its inserting to database but its not populating, i need to refresh before it shows. How do i populate this without refreshing the page that response real quick after inserted?

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_save', function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '../ajax/ajax_addJudges.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: $('#frm_org_id').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success:function(data){
       alert('success');
       fetch_data();
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Maybe it's not reaching the `.success` callback. Try adding an `.error` handler and see if it says something.

Comment: Are you getting the `success` alert?